# Do linear operators $A$, $B$ satisfying $A = B+BAB$ commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

I have two linear continuous operators $A$, $B$ on Banach space $X$ (for example, square matrices), satisfying the equation
$$
   A = B + BAB,
$$
and such that the continuous inverses $(\mathrm{Id} \pm B)^{-1}$ exist. Is it true that in this case $AB = BA$? In the case when $\|B\|<1$
 it follows from the following series expansions for $A$:
$$
  A = B + B^3 + B^5 + \cdots.
$$

*P.S.* The similar result holds, for example, if operators $A$, $B$ satisfy the equation
$$
   A = B + AB,
$$
and there exists continuous inverse $(\mathrm{Id}-B)^{-1}$. 
In this case we can show that operators $P = AB$ and $Q = BA$ satisfy the equations
$$
   P = B +PB, \\
   Q = B +QB,
$$
and hence $(P - Q)(\mathrm{Id}-B) = 0$ and $P=Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: $B = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{array}\right)$ and $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} -2/3 & 1 \\ 1 & 2/3 \end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know, if the statement will be true if we replace the "$B$" term in the equation by "$B + B^2$"? In this case this equation arises as iterated version of the equation in "P.S."

Comment: Which "$B$"?...

Comment: I mean, if we consider equation $A = B + B^2 + BAB$.

Comment: Take the same $B$ but now $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{array}\right)$.

Comment: (What makes my $B$ useful as a counterexample is that $I+B$ and $I-B$ are invertible but $I-B\otimes B$ is not. Therefore the equation $X = BXB$ has nontrivial solutions $X$, and luckily they don't commute with $B$. You can add such solutions $X$ to any given solution $A$ of either $A = B + BAB$ or $A = B+B^2+BAB$, and obtain another $A$ which will no longer commute with $B$ if the original $A$ did.)

Comment: Wait that blows my mind... $1-B^2= \mathrm{Diag}(-3,-3/4)$ is invertible or not?

Comment: $1-B^2$ is but $1-B\otimes B$ (a $4\times 4$-matrix, if you identify pairs of elements of $\left\{1,2\right\}$ with elements of $\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$ in some way) is not.

Comment: Oh as an operator acting on the 4d-space of 2 by 2 matrices, slick and sneeky!

Comment: Actually I should have said $1 - B^T \otimes B$, since that is what acts on that 4d-space. But $B^T$ is similar to $B$, so it doesn't matter in the end.

Comment: And in the case of general Banach space does the invertibility of $1-B\otimes B$ imply that $X = BXB$ has only the trivial solution?

Comment: I don't know. I wouldn't even dare to define a tensor product for Banach spaces.